# Assign data type for each column in pandas DataFrame - Python

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I want to change the data type that could be entered in an empty Pandas data frame. So I've tried the following approach but it doesn't work. 
can someone please give me a hint how to solve this issue?

```
columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E','F']


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

>>> df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C, D, E, F]
Index: []

df[[0]]=df[[0]].astype(str)
df[[1]]=df[[1]].astype(str)
df[[2]]=df[[2]].astype(int)
df.iloc[:,3:6]=df.iloc[:,3:6].astype(float)
```

Comment: In your minimal sample, you specify some list of columns and then the resultant df doesn't show these columns, also why does this matter for an empty df? The dtype will be changed once you assign data to those columns

Comment: I think only is possible set same dtype in all columns by constructor like `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, dtype=str)`

Comment: yes, it will work. [The documentation describes it](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)
so `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, dtype=str)` will give `df.dtypes` as `objects`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to construct a series or dictionary with your desired types then use `astype`

```
columns = list('ABCDEF')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

dtypes = {k: str for k in columns[:2]}
dtypes.update({columns[2]: int})
dtypes.update({k: float for k in columns[3:]})

df = df.astype(dtypes)

df.dtypes

A     object
B     object
C      int64
D    float64
E    float64
F    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: If you have any float NaN, using `astype(str)` will convert them the values to "nan"

Answer (score 0):

By default, all your columns will be of 'object' type so you might not need to force columns to be of type string as such. For the other column types, something like this might work?

```
df[['C']] = df[['C']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this problem initially but I have found a solution:

1. Convert the data frame column to a list data structure in Python.
2. Then convert the list to a series after import numpy package.
3. Using the `astype()` function convert to the desired data type.

Code:

```
list = list(data['unknown'])
series = pd.Series(list)
seriesOfTypeBool = g.astype(np.bool)
data['unknown'] = seriesOfTypeBool` <br>
```

And Simplified Version:

```
data['Action'] = pd.Series(list(data['Action'])).astype(np.bool)
```